# How to disable Guava caching?

Tags: java, guava

[JavaCachingWithGuava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=JavaCachingwithGuava.pdf&can=2&q=) suggests the canonical way to turn off caching is to set *maximumSize=0*. 
However, I'd expect the test below to pass:

```
public class LoadingCacheTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadingCacheTest.class);

    LoadingCache<String, Long> underTest;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        underTest = CacheBuilder.from("maximumSize=0").newBuilder()
                .recordStats()
                .removalListener(new RemovalListener<String, Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, Long> removalNotification) {
                        LOG.info(String.format("%s cached value %s for key %s is evicted.", removalNotification.getCause().name(), removalNotification.getValue(), removalNotification.getKey()));
                    }
                })
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Long>() {
                    private final AtomicLong al = new AtomicLong(0);
                    @Override
                    public Long load(@NotNull final String key) throws Exception {
                        LOG.info(String.format("Cache miss for key '%s'.", key));
                        return al.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void testAlwaysCacheMissIfCacheDisabled() throws Exception {
        String key1 = "Key1";
        String key2 = "Key2";
        underTest.get(key1);
        underTest.get(key1);
        underTest.get(key2);
        underTest.get(key2);
        LOG.info(underTest.stats().toString());
        Assert.assertThat(underTest.stats().missCount(), is(equalTo(4L)));
    }
}
```

That is, turning off the cache always results in a cache miss.

The test fails, though. Is my interpretation incorrect?

Comment: Why are you using `from("maximumSize=0")` rather than `.maximumSize(0)`? The `from(String spec)` method is intended to be used when you're getting the cache configuration from some properties/settings such as the command line, a file, etc. When you're doing the configuration programmatically like this, you should use the actual methods.

Comment: Thanks, Colin. It's just done like this for the purpose of this unit-test example -the real component gets the cache spec spring-injected as props

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method [`newBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#newBuilder%28%29) constructs a new [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) instance with default settings, ignoring the call to [`from`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#from%28java.lang.String%29). However, you want to construct a [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) with a specific maximum size. So, remove the call to [`newBuider`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#newBuilder%28%29). You should use your call to [`build`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#build%28%29) to get a [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) matching your spec rather than getting one with default settings:

```
underTest = CacheBuilder.from("maximumSize=0")
                .recordStats()
                .removalListener(new RemovalListener<String, Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, Long> removalNotification) {
                        LOG.info(String.format("%s cached value %s for key %s is evicted.", removalNotification.getCause().name(), removalNotification.getValue(), removalNotification.getKey()));
                    }
                })
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Long>() {
                    private final AtomicLong al = new AtomicLong(0);
                    @Override
                    public Long load(@NotNull final String key) throws Exception {
                        LOG.info(String.format("Cache miss for key '%s'.", key));
                        return al.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                });
```